I tried to add a footer to the group_header in the table generated by the gtsummary package, but failed
Title: How to Add Footnotes to Group Headers in gtsummary Tables?
Body:
I am using the gtsummary package in R to generate summary tables and I would like to add specific footnotes to different model groups. I tried using the modify_table_styling function to add a footnote to the group header, but it did not work as expected. Here is the code I attempted:
library(gtsummary)

Model1 <-
  glm(response ~ age, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE,include = age)

Model2 <- glm(response ~ age + grade, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE,include = age)

Model <- tbl_stack(list(Model1, Model2),group_header = c("Model 1", "Model 2"))


Model <- Model |> 
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = groupname_col ,  
    rows =groupname_col  == "Model 1",  
    footnote = "Model 1: Not adjusted"
  )

Model       

When I run this code, the footnote does not appear under the group header as expected. I want to display the footnote “Model 1: Not adjusted” under the "Model 1" group header. How can I modify the code to achieve this?
enter image description here
